# npm scripts, browser-sync and proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, proxy, gulp, browser-sync, npm-scripts

I am trying to convert my gulp build env to use pure npm scripts. I have been able to solve most issues but I am a bit stuck on browser-sync and using proxy-middleware. In our current project we have a ASP.NET backend and therefore I need to proxy some urls. 
This is the config for proxies used in our gulp file

```
 gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    var apiProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/api');
    apiProxy.route = '/api';
    var mvnDepsProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/mvndeps');
    mvnDepsProxy.route = '/mvndeps';
    var imagesProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/images');
    imagesProxy.route = '/images';
    var ngscriptsProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/ng-scripts');
    ngscriptsProxy.route = '/ng-scripts';
    var commonProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/common');
    commonProxy.route = '/common';

    if (baseParentFolder != '') {
        var proxies = [proxy(apiProxy), proxy(mvnDepsProxy), proxy(imagesProxy), proxy(ngscriptsProxy), proxy(commonProxy)];
    }
    else
        var proxies = [proxy(apiProxy)];

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: baseFolder,
            middleware: proxies
        },
        open: openBrowserOnServe,
        port: developmentUiPort
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this using only npm scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working today. I ended up creating a separate file for handling browser sync:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var url = require('url');
var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
var iisPort = 61209;
var iisAppContext = "/App";

var apiProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/api');
apiProxy.route = '/api';
var mvnDepsProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/mvndeps');
mvnDepsProxy.route = '/mvndeps';
var imagesProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/images');
imagesProxy.route = '/images';
var ngscriptsProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/ng-scripts');
ngscriptsProxy.route = '/ng-scripts';
var commonProxy = url.parse('http://localhost:' + iisPort + iisAppContext + '/common');
commonProxy.route = '/common';

var proxies = [proxy(apiProxy), proxy(mvnDepsProxy), proxy(imagesProxy), proxy(ngscriptsProxy), proxy(commonProxy)];

browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: './',
        middleware: proxies,
        files: ["css/**/*.css", "**/*.html", "scripts/*.js"]
    },
    open: false,
    port: 9009
});

browserSync.watch(["scripts/*.js", "**/*.html", "css/*.css"]).on("change", browserSync.reload);
```

I then call this from npm scripts like this:

```
    "scripts": {
    "bs": "node browsersync.js"
}
```